# do I need to report a closed account on modelo 720 in Spain?

Tags: taxes, spain

I am filling out the dastardly modelo 720 (reporting global income) in Spain. My question is about an account, say account ONE, I had in the previous years but I closed it last year and moved that money to a different account, say account TWO. The modelo has three categories of accounts represented by codes A, M and C like so.

A
Bien o derecho que se declara por primera vez o que se incorpora en el ejercicio de la declaración.
M
Bien o derecho que ya ha sido declarado en ejercicios anteriores.
C
Bien o derecho que se declara porque se extingue la titularidad, se revoca la autorización o poder de disposición, o se extingue cualquier otra forma de titularidad real sobre el mismo.

Do I declare account ONE with code C and account TWO with code A? I am not sure what code C is for… why would one want to declare an account on which one has their *titularidad extingue*? If that refers to a closed account, that it would be an account with 0 value.

or

Do I forget about account ONE and just declare account TWO with code A?